# CUDA efficient kernel invocation

Tags: cuda, gpu

Guys please confirm if my thinking is right.

Suppose I have a kernel function `mykernel(double *array)`. I want the code inside the kernel to be executed 128-times. I can do this in two ways when invoking the kernel from host:

```
mykernel<<<128, 1>>>(myarray);
//or
mykernel<<<1, 128>>>(myarray);
```

With first invocation I will create 128 blocks, each running 1 thread. In second invocation I will create 1 block with 128 threads. But since the code inside kernel is working on the same array, it is more efficient to use the second invocation.

Am I a fool or should I stick to learning CUDA? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. The first invocation will create multiple blocks, but each block will be too small to efficiently use the multiprocessors of your GPU (they're even smaller than the warp size). The second invocation won't make use of the multiple multiprocessors on your GPU. If you really only need 128 threads then I'd suggest you to try something along the lines of

```
mykernel<<<4, 32>>>(myarray);
```

But generally you'll need to benchmark your code with different parameters to optimize the performance anyway, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I forgot to ask another thing in my answer: do I need to copy simple variables (an int for e.g.) to device the same way as arrays?

Comment: No, you don't have to. In fact it might be preferable to pass those directly as kernel parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective utilization of CUDA threads is in blocks of 32.
These are called warps.

1 warp=32 threads.

So, model your code  keeping this in mind.

Comment: According to http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/cuda_webinars_WarpsAndOccupancy.pdf (slide #9), small block sizes should be avoided and they suggest that 128~256 threads. I guess, at the end of the day, one has to experiment with these sizes to optimise the performance of their codes.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean execute 128 times? If you need to iterate over the array for 128 times and each iteration depends on the previous results then you need to chop up the array into reasonable pieces and run code then synchronize and repeat.

In general if you only have 128 elements then running them all in one block should be alright because the access to the memory may be faster.